# How to write data to a Django temp file?

Tags: python-3.x, django

***Hello Community!***

I have a small application that allows you to download certain multimedia content from an HTML template.

To save resources, I want this file to be stored only on the PC of the users who visit the eventual website, which is why I will use a temporary file NamedTemporaryFile that the FrameWork Django provides.

Part of the code consists of:

**HTML TEMPLATE:**

```
...
<input type = "button" value = "Download" onclick = "window.open('download')">
...
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from ProjectApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('download', views.download),
    ...
]
```

**views.py:**

```
import os
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

def download(request):

    newfile = NamedTemporaryFile (suffix='.txt', mode='w+b')

    file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'test.txt') # MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    filename = os.path.basename('archive_test.txt')
    chunk_size = 8192
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        FileWrapper(newfile, chunk_size), content_type="application/octet-stream")
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'

    return response
```

It should be noted that as I show it, it works as I wish, since a download dialog appears in the browser with the archive_test.txt file in a "starting" state.

What I want is that from that moment on, the information that it will contain begins to be written to said file that is being "downloaded".

I used for this example a TXT file but it could be a JPG image, MP3 audio, MP4 video, among others.

***Thank you all for your comments and/or suggestions!***

[image: In this image you can see how the file is in "waiting".]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`FileResponse(...)`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse) class as

```
from django.http.response import FileResponse


def download(request):
    file_name = "path/to/the/file.txt"
    return FileResponse(open(file_name, "rb"), as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Yes I could, but  in that case I would be using an existing path (file_name = "path/to/the/file.txt") and what I want is to work with temporary files.

Comment: Also, I use StreamingHttpResponse because I read in the official Django documentation that it is better for large files.

Comment: The first parameter of `FileResponse` accepts the ***file-stream*** object, so you can pass the same. Also, the `FileResponse` is the sub class of `StreamingHttpResponse`